# selecting an individual element from a list within a list using .where and .select

Tags: c#, string, list, ienumerable, rectangles

I have a `List<>` of type `world` and within each world element is a `List<>` of type `item` which in itself contains a `Rectangle` and a `string`

heres the structure of world

```
`class world
    public Items[] items { get; set; }

    public world(int nooflevels, int noofitems)
    {
        //when creating a world make the items
        items = new Items[noofitems];

        for (int i = 0; i < noofitems; i++)
        {
            items[i] = new Items();
        }
     }        
}`
```

and item

```
class Items
{
    public new Rectangle spriterect;
    public string type { get; set; }

    public Items()
    {
        spriterect.X = 0;
        spriterect.Y = 0;
        spriterect.Width = 0;
        spriterect.Height = 0;
        type = "default";
    }

}
```

this list of worlds was created like this
    `List<world> Worlds = new List<world>();`

i was trying to get a specific rectangle out of the list of items based on the type

```
    void getitem(string thetype, int world)
    {
        Rectangle  a = Worlds[world].
                       items.Where(f=> f.type == thetype).
                       Select(g => g.spriterect);
    }
```

so i was hoping this would select the item[].spriterect that contained the .type thetype
and i want it to return the rectangle in that item but it returns an IEnumerable
how do i get it to return the single rectangle based on the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should select single item from items. If there should be single rectangle of specified type, then use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
var item = Worlds[world].items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.type == thetype);
if (item != null) 
    a = item.spriterect;
```

If you completely sure that there is always exist rectangle of specified type, then simply use `Single`:

```
Rectangle a = Worlds[world].items.Single(i => i.type == thetype).spriterect;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use [`.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) after you `.Select`.

Single will throw an Exception if there is not exactly one match.

```
Rectangle a = Worlds[world]
                   .items.Where(f=> f.type == thetype)
                   Select(g => g.spriterect).Single();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of where use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx). If it doesn't find the item, it will return null.

```
var primary = Worlds[world].FirstOrDefault(f=> f.type == thetype);

if (primary != null)
   return primary.spriterect;

return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only know you will only ever get one value you can use `Single`, or `SingleOrDefault` if you know the item may not exist.

```
//use if you know the rectangle will be there, and there will be only 1 that matches the criteria
Rectangle a = Worlds[world].items.Single(f => f.type == thetype).spriterect;

//use if the rectangle may not be there, and if it is there will be only 1 that matches the criteria
var item = Worlds[world].items.SingleOrDefault(f => f.type == thetype);
if (item != null)
    Rectangle a = item.spriterect;
```

Comment: You are missing a select as this returns an item not a Rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` function returns a collection (eveything that meets the criteria), rather than just a single item. You would want to use either `First` or `Single`, noting that `Single` will throw an exception if there is more than one matching the criteria (and both will throw if there are none).